# create a program that communicate with the arduino using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, arduino, ethernet

I have to create a program that send comand to the arduino;
The program must be the client and the arduino the server.
So the question is: what is the code to start the communication?
P.S. the arduino obviously have an ethernet shield on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have searched on google, i found this :

For Arduino :

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Ethernet

For Windows :

http://www.nullskull.com/articles/20020323.asp

Answer (score 1):

I've not used Arduino myself but a have a look at [Arduino Playground](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/CmdMessenger):

> CmdMessenger is a messaging library for the Arduino Platform (and .NET/Mono platform). It uses the serial port as transport layer. To use CmdMessenger, we define a list of command identifiers, then attach callback / handler functions for received messages.
>
> The message format is: **Cmd Id, param 1, [...] , param N;**
>
> The library gives the following functionality:
>
> - Sending and receiving commands
> - Calling of associated functions on received commands
> - Sending and receiving zero to many arguments per command
> - Sending and receiving of all primary types. This includes bytes, longs, ints, floats and doubles.
> - Sending and receiving in plain text form (human readable, robust) or in binary form (efficient)
>
> The library can be downloaded through the Arduino or PlatformIO library manager, or downloaded as a stand-alone package, see the [read-me page](https://github.com/thijse/Arduino-CmdMessenger).